# How do I use calculated value date in Sharepoint lists field to find a date+30 days?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list I've built in Sharepoint, where one of the fields is a date that the user enters.
I want to add another field, which is a calculated value field that needs to be the date provided by the user + 30 days.
What formula do I need to pass to the calculated value field to achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a new Calculated column
2. In the Forumla box, enter something like this:
       =TEXT([existing date column]+30,"yyyy-mm-dd")
   You can use any date format string you like instead of "yyyy-mm-dd"
3. Make the data type "Date and Time"
4. Make the date and time format "Date Only"